# NLTagger tags every word as OtherWord and name scheme as Other

Tags: ios, swift, nlp

I tried Apple's [own example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/identifying_people_places_and_organizations):

```
import NaturalLanguage

let text = "The American Red Cross was established in Washington, D.C., by Clara Barton."

let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.nameType])
tagger.string = text

let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace, .joinNames]
let tags: [NLTag] = [.personalName, .placeName, .organizationName]

tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .nameType, options: options) { tag, tokenRange in 
    // Get the most likely tag, and print it if it's a named entity.
    if let tag = tag, tags.contains(tag) {
        print("\(text[tokenRange]): \(tag.rawValue)")
    }
        
    // Get multiple possible tags with their associated confidence scores.
    let (hypotheses, _) = tagger.tagHypotheses(at: tokenRange.lowerBound, unit: .word, scheme: .nameType, maximumCount: 1)
    print(hypotheses)
        
   return true
}
```

But it returns all name tags as `Other`. I also tried another example of tagging the sentence with lexical class, and it also tags every word as `OtherWord`:

```
var text = "The American Red Cross was established in Washington, D.C., by Clara Barton."

let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lexicalClass])
tagger.string = text

let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace, .joinNames]

print("language", tagger.dominantLanguage)

tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: options) { tag, tokenRange in
    // Get the most likely tag, and print it if it's a named entity.
    if let tag = tag {
        print("\(text[tokenRange]): \(tag.rawValue)")
    }

   return true
}
```

I tried the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311279/linguistic-tagger-incorrectly-tagging-as-otherword) by setting language orthography but it didn't help:

```
//tagger.setOrthography(NSOrthography(dominantScript: "Latn", languageMap: ["Latn": ["en"]]), range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex)
tagger.setOrthography(NSOrthography.defaultOrthography(forLanguage: "en-US"), range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex)
```

Anybody has a clue why is it like this?

By the way, my Xcode version is the latest one as of today, 14.3.

Comment: Your first set of code works fine for me in a macOS Playground running in Xcode 14.3. It finds "American Red Cross" as an organization name, "Washington" as a place name, and "Clara Barton" as a personal name. The same code in an iOS Playground in Xcode 14.3 gives just "Other". Running on an iOS 15.5 simulated device gives the correct results. Fails on a simulated iOS 16.4 device. Seems to be an iOS 16.4 issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking various environments and confirming the case on iOS 16.4.

Comment: I tried Xcode 14.3 + my iPhone (physical device) running iOS 16.4.1, and it works there too. So it does look like this is a regression on iOS 16.4 (at least on simulator). Could you answer this question and I'll accept it?

Comment: Running into this also and discouragingly on Xcode 15 beta 7, iOS 17 simulator.  Anyone get it working?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a regression of Xcode 14.3. I downloaded Xcode 14.2 and the NLTagger correctly works for `.nameType` and `.lexicalClass` tagging.

This regression in Xcode 14.3 also affects `NLEmbedding`. For example, the following code gets word neighbors correctly in 14.2 but returns nil embedding in Xcode 14.3:

```
if let embedding = NLEmbedding.wordEmbedding(for: .english) {
  print("found embedding")
  print("embeddings for family: \(embedding.neighbors(for: "family", maximumCount: 3))")
  print("embeddings for science: \(embedding.neighbors(for: "science", maximumCount: 3))")
} else {
  print("no embedding found")
}
```